# Why do we brew beer but make wine?

Tags: nouns

Why not brew wine and make beer? Non native speaker so I can't fully discern the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to keep things simple and just _drink_ them :)

Comment: RASPBERRIES, STRAWBERRIES LYRICS - KINGSTON TRIO: "Ah! les fraises et les framboises et les bon vins [que] nous avons bus. // La, la, la, la, la, la, la, la, la, la, la, la, la. // Raspberries, strawberries, **the good wines we brew**. //
Here's to the girls of the countryside, // the ones we drink 'em to."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the difference has to do with the technical process. Beer is boiled, steeped, mixed with wort, cooked and so on. Liquor is distilled and wine simply ferments. Unless you boil and sweeten the wine with spices and such. Then, wine is mulled.

Tea is brewed also because the process of infusing and boiling and steeping is part of what it is to brew.

Comment: Dan is right. Look here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=brew

Comment: I suppose beer was a skilled craft like cooking while wine just magically happened without understanding wwhy

Comment: Some wines require a boiling process to extract flavours; elderflower and dandelion are two. Of course, the word 'wine' is often used in the more specific sense.

Comment: Wort is the product of boiling grains and hops, not something that is mixed in after boiling.