# Can you brew wine, or is the word "brew" specific to Beer, coffee, and tea?

Tags: meaning, verbs, context

I would like to know whether or not wine can be brewed, and secondly if the wine-making process is considered brewing. It seems that some definitions are specific to beer, coffee, and tea, where others are not.

Comment: Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105330/why-do-we-brew-beer-but-make-wine   Short answer: The technical aspects of wine-making do not include brewing.

Comment: _Brewing_ involves heating a liquid that contains vegetable matter, to extract something from it. In the case of beer, the liquid is water and the vegetable matter is malted barley and other grains, and they are boiled for a long time to make the wort that ferments into beer or ale. In the case of wine, there is no brewing, because the liquid is grape juice, which is not heated before fermenting.